# SQL query not getting correct result in declare set statement in tsql

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a query as

```
declare @aa varchar(50)

set @aa = concat('''',year(getdate())-67,'''')

select * from dimcustomer where cast(datepart(year,BirthDate) as varchar(50)) = @aa
```

I have datatype for `birthdate` as `varchar(50)`. But unable to get any results, getting zero records

What is the wrong with my query ??? help is appreciated !!!

Comment: *"I have datatype for birthdate as varchar(50)"* There's your problem. Fix your design. There are *multiple* date and time data types to choose from, and all (apart from `time`) are *infinitely* a better data type choice for a date of birth.

Comment: Not to mention that your expression `concat('''',year(getdate())-56,'''')` returns the value `'1967'` (the single quotes (`'`) are part of the value, as a literal it would be `'''1967'''`). What "date" is `'1967'`?

Comment: Also SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine, and what version?

Comment: Hello @ThomA Your are right question has to be corrected I am using following query but also not getting any results

Comment: Of course you won't, your query is effectively `WHERE Birthdate = '''1967'''` that makes no sense.

Comment: Why is your data type for a *date* not a `date`?

Comment: Can you please provide some example DDL/DML for your `dimcustomer` table? Its hard to determine why a query returns no rows when we can't see the data it's querying. It would also be helpful if you updated the question to reflect changes you may have made.

Comment: datatype for birthdate is varchar(50)

Comment: *"datatype for birthdate is varchar(50)"* We know, and that's the **problem**. Use a [Date and Time Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes). Fix your design, fix the problem.

Comment: Your variable still contains the value `'1956'`. Why are there single quotes in the string? Have you tried removing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do NOT include single quotes with variable name to include them in SQL. Quotes are only needed for **literal** values in the SQL, not variables:

```
declare @aa varchar(50)
set @aa = year(getdate())-67
select * from dimcustomer where cast(datepart(year,BirthDate) as varchar(50)) = @aa
```

Second, do NOT convert datetime parts to compare as strings. This is (*by far*) the slowest and most-error prone way to do this.

```
declare @aa int
set @aa = year(getdate())-67
select * from dimcustomer where datepart(year,BirthDate) = @aa
```

Third, structure the comparison so you don't need to make ANY modifications to the stored data. This will allow you match up with indexes and avoid per-row conversions for an entire table when you may only need a few of the rows:

```
declare @aa Date
set @aa = DateFromParts(year(getdate())-67, 1, 1)
select * from dimcustomer where BirthDate >= @aa and BirthDate < DATEADD(year, 1, @aa)
```

Fourth, **NEVER** define date columns as varchar. You can't use functions like `datepart()` if it's a varchar, you can't index them properly, they take up more storage and memory, and you stop the database from ensuring you have valid data in the column.

As it is, you'll need to cast the value to a datetime (or similar). This breaks any chance of index use on the column, which cuts to the core of database performance, and forces you to do the conversion on *every row in the table*... even rows you don't need. Worse, thanks to cultural/internationalization issues these conversion are not the simple or fast conversions you might expect, but are rather *really slow and finicky*. Finally, it leaves you open to a *broken query* that won't run if you get any data into the table that won't convert:

```
declare @aa int
set @aa = year(getdate())-67
select * from dimcustomer where datepart(year,cast(BirthDate as date)) = @aa
```

Comment: Considering that the OP has stated the column`BirthDate` is a `varchar(50)` and considering that they think `'1967'` (single quotes (`'`) included) is a valid "date", I don't doubt for one second doubt that `datepart(year,BirthDate)` is going to error due to a poorly string formatted date.

Comment: @ThomA If they're calling `DatePart()` successfully, it's not actually a varchar

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - not entirely true - all it means is the column can be implicitly converted to a `DATETIME`, it could potentially be a number of data types.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your design, then secondly your query. Firstly, fix your design by changing your column `BirthDate` to an actual date. We'll need to "bin" any crud data in your table first though and we'll assume that implicit conversion is "good enough":

```sql
UPDATE dbo.dimcustomer 
SET BirthDate = CONVERT(varchar(10),TRY_CONVERT(date,BirthDate),112); --Convert to an ISO format
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.dimcustomer ALTER COLUMN BirtDate date NULL; --NULL as I assume you have crud data
```

Now that the data type is fixed, you can use a date boundary for a SARGable query:

```sql
DECLARE @BirthYear int;

SET @BirthYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, -67,GETDATE()));

SELECT <Explicit list of columns>
FROM dbo.dimcustomer
WHERE BirthDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(@BirthYear,1,1)
  AND BirthDate < DATEFROMPARTS(@BirthYear+1,1,1);
```